# How to remove comma and "" from JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which I need to remove the commas and "" surrounding each item in the array. I used `.join('')` and also `toString()`. This only gave me `0 1 2 3` .

What I have:

```
Array = ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
```

Need it to look like this:

```
Array = ["0 1 2 3"]
```

Comment: Why do you want the array to contain a single string? If you want a single string, why bother with the array?

Comment: That result seems very strange

Comment: So you want to turn an array of four strings into an array with a single space-separated string?

Comment: Why do you need an array with a single string?

Comment: I need to pass this information to a 3rd party application. Basically, what I am doing is selecting multiple days for a schedule and passing the array with the days selected. It will only recognize the days if the array is as:
array = ["0 1 2 3"]

Comment: That's not an answer, can't that third party application use strings? If it can only use arrays, then excuse me but why the hell do you need to concatenate it?

Comment: @Bálint Sorry I am new to coding, so not sure what other way to go. I am passing this in a JSON object

Comment: Overriding native `Array` propably isn't a good idea.

Comment: {string: <string comes here>} boom, JSON

Comment: @Bálint How is that? [Boom](http://json.org/) ; ).

Comment: @Teemu javascript objects are essentially JSON objects, try converting it to string

Comment: @Bálint No they are not, JSON is a data-interchange format, it has nothing to do with JS objects, except the format is based on quite similar syntax.

Comment: @Bálint The only existing [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is an intrinsic object in JS engines ...

Comment: @Teemu JSON -> Javascript object notation

Comment: @Bálint It's just a name for a data-interchange format. If that would have originally been named for example as `DIF`, we probably wouldn't even have begun this discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `join()`

```js
var ar = ["0", "1", "2", "3"];
console.log([ar.join(' ')])
```

Comment: I believe the OP has already used it: *I used `.join('')` and also `toString()`.*

Comment: I'm curious why this is down voted, it achieves exactly what he wants....

Comment: @PraveenKumar yeah, but he's using `.join` and wrapping it in array literal to get the exact result the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can get the result I need with your answer but my JSON object is still printing ["0", "1", "2", "3"]

Comment: @Heather Can you create a fiddle, i am not sure what you mean.

Comment: It worked for the JSON object as well. Didn't realize I was updating it.
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 5):

```
var newArray = [oldArray.join(' ')];
```

Or alternatively

```
var newArray = oldArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + " " + b;
});
```